# Custom mvc htmlhelper candidate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

We have a bunch of pages where there is a audio/video player inside the page.

Instead of adding all the js/css required for the player in each of these pages, I am thinking of adding a `@Html.MediaPlayer` helper that will take the file path as a parameter and spits out the js/css and the html script required to display the player. Is this a good idea? Is there a better a way to do it?

Comment: You may get advantage of Html5 for this task. Have a look a this post: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249374/Demo-Application-showing-the-use-of-Html5MVCWebCon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a custom reusable helper for this scenario looks like a good approach. An alternative method would be to use a partial view that could be included.